# Xcode 5.1 shows error your App is not campatibale with iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone

i have make a universal app for iPhone and iPad view, but when am going to upload this app. i got some error related to icons and compatibility issue.

i going to launch my app for ios version 6.0 to 7.1.

Application loader show me error that your app is not compatible with iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCODE 5.1 didn't have default splash screens.

so add splash screen for iPhone 5 That's it.

and it didn't rename 640*1136 image as Default-568h@2x.png. in use assets catalog.

so, please rename your splash screen by own. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need To add The Splash For iPhone 5 Thats it.